# fillna() multiple pandas column using a third

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to fill **open, high, low**  with the **close** value in the dataframe using a single line of code. Not sure why *Example 1* does not work, where as *Example 2* does. Am I missing something here?

If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears. I am ffill NaN values for Open, High, Low using the Close from the prior time-period. I am also setting volume to 0

*Example 1*

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_pickle('../data/minute_bar_ESU9.pickle')
data['ticker'] = 'ESU9'
data['volume'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
data['close'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

data[['open','high','low']] = data[['open','high','low']].fillna(value=data.close)

print(data.head(4))


                       open    high     low  close  volume ticker
datetime                                                         
2009-06-10 15:30:00  936.00  936.00  935.50  936.0    37.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:31:00  935.75  935.75  935.50  935.5    26.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:32:00     NaN     NaN     NaN  935.5     0.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:33:00  935.75  936.00  935.75  936.0    13.0   ESU9
```

*Example 2:*

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_pickle('../data/minute_bar_ESU9.pickle')
data['ticker'] = 'ESU9'
data['volume'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
data['close'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

data.open = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)
data.high = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)
data.low = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)

print(data.head(4))


                       open    high     low  close  volume ticker
datetime                                                         
2009-06-10 15:30:00  936.00  936.00  936.00  936.0    37.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:31:00  935.75  935.75  935.75  935.5    26.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:32:00  935.50  935.50  935.50  935.5     0.0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:33:00  935.75  935.75  935.75  936.0    13.0   ESU9
```

---

**Update: Looks like it completes faster using example 2.**

```
Using:
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(value=x.close),axis=1
Total elapsed time: 42.797965 for shape: (131025, 6)

Using:
data.open = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)
data.high = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)
data.low = data.open.fillna(value=data.close)
Total elapsed time: 0.055636 for shape: (131025, 6)

Using:
data = data.T.fillna(data.close).T
Total elapsed time: 48.683746 for shape: (131025, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(value=x.close),axis=1)
print(data.head(4))
```

Answer (score 2):

In *Example 1* you are attempting to fill in missing along axis one... or horizontally.  Two things to note: one, you should be using the `axis=1` parameter, two that won't work because it isn't implemented yet.

```
df.fillna(df.close, axis=1)
```

> NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column

***work around***
*transpose the data, then fill*

```
df.T.fillna(df.close).T

                      open    high     low  close volume ticker
datetime                                                        
2009-06-10 15:30:00     936     936   935.5    936     37   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:31:00  935.75  935.75   935.5  935.5     26   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:32:00   935.5   935.5   935.5  935.5      0   ESU9
2009-06-10 15:33:00  935.75     936  935.75    936     13   ESU9
```